# Externals в git

Tags: git, bitbucket

Как в репозиторий добавить ссылки на папки из другого репозитория? В SVN это называется как-то типа Externals. Есть ли что-то подобное в bitbucket?

Comment: а какой тип репозитория вы используете на bitbucket? git? hg?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Похоже что git

Comment: Вам наверное нужен  как в svn sparse checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **Git** это называется **Подмодуль**.

Вот эта команда

```
git submodule add git://github.com/chneukirchen/rack.git rack
```

добавит ссылку на **подмодуль** в ваш репозиторий.

Более детально вы можете прочитать в документации о [Подмодулях](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Comment: Таким образом добавится весь репозиторий? Можно как-то выбрать конкретные папки, а не весь репозиторий добавлять?

Comment: таким образом добавится ссылка на конкретный репозиторий. после коммита зафиксируется еще и конкретное состояние этого репозитория.

Comment: С добавлением подмодуля разобрался. И все-же остался вопрос... Можно ли при создании подмодуля добавлять не весь репозиторий целиком, а только определенные папки из него? А то уж очень много бесполезных для данного репозитория (куда добавляется подмодуль) файликов в рабочей копии получается.

Comment: репозиторий добавляется целиком. возможно вам подойдет менеджер зависимостей, а не подмодуль.